Show where a group of four students are sucked into a game on a laptop
Around 2018, I believe I watched a show in Russian as we are a Ukrainian household, but I don't remember if the show was Russian.
But anyways, a group of 4 students find this laptop and open it, and a game loads, then they pick their characters, and a teacher walks in and sees them. As soon as she walks in, they are sucked into that laptop. I remember one of them was like a digitised archery.

Was this live-action or animated? Also, were the students male, female, or a combination?

This does sound a bit like the 2017 movie Jumanji: Welcome to the Jungle in some respects:

It is about 4 students.
They do use a computing device (though not exactly a laptop, rather an old game console).
They are sucked into it (with a graphical effect that implies they are "dematerialized" in some way).
They do pick their in-game characters before this happens.

However, no-one walks in on them; they are just shown to be gone.
Also, while the characters have various in-game skills, none of them is specifically an archer.
Here is the scene: 


While it is in English, maybe the visuals ring a bell for you.

I don't know if the time fits, but there was a series Reboot: the Guardian Code- a spinoff of the CGI-animated series Reboot. Unlike the source material which took place entirely within the computer and where 'users' of the outside human world were seen as mysterious and unknowable, in the spinoff four (at least) human young teenagers could somehow 'enter' the world of 'Mainframe' Tron-style and help fight villains such as the viruses (virii?) Megabyte and Hexadecimal.

Are any of them archers?
